# Quero converter Timedelta para float

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, numpy

Tenho um Dataframe no qual uma das colunas é o intervalo de tempo em dias entre a pesquisa de uma linha para outra, os dados dessa coluna estão no formta Timedelta, como no exemplo: Timedelta('61 days 00:00:00')

Preciso converter essa coluna para Float, para poder operar ela

Tentei converter da seguinte forma:

```
i = 1
ts= df_h['Intervalo Pesquisa'][i].total_seconds()
ts
```

Que funciona perfeitamente e me devolve um float, porém quando coloco a função dentro de um for, ela não roda:

```
td_list = []
for i in range (8410):
    ts= df_h['Intervalo Pesquisa'][i].total_seconds()
    td = ts/86400 #dividir total de segundos pelos segundos de um dia 
    td_list.append(td)
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-99d7df4ff6da> in <module>()
  1 td_list = []
  2 for i in range (8410):
----> 3     ts= df_h['Intervalo Pesquisa'][i].total_seconds()
  4     td = ts/86400 #dividir total de segundos pelos segundos de um dia
  5     td_list.append(td)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Não sei porque não está funcionando.

Aceito sugestões de outros métodos para converter Timedelta para Float

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, se `df_h['Intervalo Pesquisa'][1].total_seconds()` lança o erro `'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'` é porque nessa coluna os valores são do tipo `int`. Usa `df_h.dtypes` para verificar os tipos e tem que aparecer `Intervalo Pesquisa timedelta64[ns]`.

Segundo, nunca use `for`, é muito ineficiente, use `apply`. Um exemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = {'Intervalo Pesquisa': [pd.Timedelta('%d days 00:00:00' % i) for i in range(3)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dados)

td_list = df['Intervalo Pesquisa'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/86400).tolist()
print(td_list)
```

A saída:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```